# Gradle Failed: transformClassesWithDexForDebug with jdk 1.8

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, build.gradle, firebase-storage

All day I have a challenge with resolve update of some dependencies in my new project.

This is my **build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com...."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and **error** is:

[image]

**Error:**

```
"Execution failed for task: ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/home/bin/java" finished with non zero-exit value 2
```

The problem was showing when I tried to upload an image to Firebase storage. There was error with an internet connection etc. I decided to make update of libraries. After this there is an error with jdk 1.8.

Could somebody help me to resolve this challenge?

Regards

Comment: You need jack toolchain if you want java8 features. Also do you need  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1' instead of using specific ones that you need https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. Check Selectively compiling APIs into your executable

Comment: Next time, copy and paste the error instead of taking a screenshot. It's barely readable unless opened the image on a new tab.

Comment: @th3pat3l Thank you for information. I provided my question about your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you would also want to check and resolve version conflicts in your app's dependencies.
Also check if you have enabled multidex in your app.

I had a similar issue. In my app I am using guava-retrying library, which was fetching google guava library version 21. Guava version 21 requires JDK 1.8 without providing back porting support and this was causing this error in my case.

I was able to solve it by including the guava-retrying library so that it uses version 19.0 of guava library:

```
compile ("com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:2.0.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. i get Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForFlavorQuaDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/m...uild/intermediates/multi-dex/flavorQua/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/miguelsilva/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))

Comment: Some of the libraries are adding the same dependencies (I think Guava in your case). You need to find the conflicting libraries by running dependencies gradle task and exclude duplicate dependencies. Check for libraries like Dagger 2 and exclude Guava from them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to enable Multidex for your application.

add the Multidex library to your `dependencies`, then enable Multidex in `defaultConfig`.

Example:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com...."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Then in `AndroidManifest.xml", enable Multidex installation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle